# Convert a letter to the corresponding letter on the opposite counting direction in the alphabet

Tags: java

I am self-studying Java and I am very at the beginning learning the basics. With below code I am trying to convert a letter to the corresponding letter on the opposite counting direction in the alphabet(i.e A to Z or Z to A etc.). It works for a single letter but not for a series of letters. How can I make it work with more than one letter? If you can use the simplest way it would be good as I am quite new in Java. I don't(know how to) export any built in classes etc.

Thank you.

```
class Turner{
    int find(int fin, int mi,int ma,char ch[]){
        int mid = (ma+mi)/2;
        int x;
        if(ch[mid]==fin)
            return mid;
        else if(fin<ch[mid])
            return(find(fin, mi,mid-1,ch));
        else
             return x = find(fin,(mid+1),ma,ch);
    }

}

class Turn {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        Turner try1 = new Turner();  

        char arra[] = new char[26];
        char arrb[] = new char[26];
        int min = 0;
        int max = arra.length;
        char a = 'A';
        char b = 'Z';
        int i;
        char letter;
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            arra[i]=a;
            a++;
            arrb[i]=b;
            b--;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");

        letter = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.print(arrb[try1.find(letter,min,max,arra)]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered just doing some math?

```
letter = Character.toUpperCase((char)System.in.read());
System.out.print((char)('Z' - (letter - 'A'));
```

And it works for only one letter because you are not repeating the conversion procedure. The program reads one `char`, prints its opposite and then terminates.

All you have to do is to put the read and print code inside some sort of loop, so every time it runs it will promptly wait for the next letter.

```
while (true) {
    letter = Character.toUpperCase((char)System.in.read());
    if ((letter > 'Z') || (letter < 'A'))
        break;  // user inputted an invalid symbol, terminating the program
    System.out.print((char)('Z' - (letter - 'A')));
}
```

Comment: I did consider writing something like ('A' + 26 - (letter - 'A')) but it didn't happen :) It should be 25 though. Just out of curiosity have you tried the code you wrote? You would've realized that it's slightly wrong(1 digit). That is so cool to write a piece of code without running it but knowing that it'd work 99.99% I didn't know I could use while loop like this. Thank you all

Comment: Oh well It's not like I'm supposed to provide compile-proof answers or anything. But even better, just default it to `'Z'`, not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: You got me wrong. As I am new in this computing/programming world I am trying to understand how you guys are writing the codes. It's actually good that it's not compile-proof so that I can do something. I thought I was making a compliment actually :) Anyway, Would you mind giving me some advice on how to improve/develop my programming skills? Is there anyway to contact you in private? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your function (they are called methods in java) works, good. Just put it in a `while` loop or otherwise call it when you need it.

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done){
    System.out.println("Enter a letter (space to quit): ");
    letter = (char)System.in.read();
    if(letter == ' ') done = true;
    else System.out.print(arrb[try1.find(letter,min,max,arra)]);
}
```

And Havenard is right, this can be written considerably more simply, with arithmetic on `char`s. For instance `ch -'a' == 1` evaluates to `true` when `ch` is 'b'.

One other note: `find` and `Turner` aren't very descriptive names for what these things do. Before long it could get messy without simple and to the point naming.

Comment: Taking the "System.out.println("Enter a letter (space to quit): "); " outside of the loop makes it better because it writes the same thing every time when it goes through the loop. Also, need to enter letter and then space to be able to quite otherwise it loops unnecessarily long. Thank you to show me another way of using while loop and giving me constructive feedback on my code. I'll try to improve my naming.

Answer (score 0):

A character has an equivalent numerical value. For "basic characters", this mapping is called ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Now, in java, you can convert a `char` into an `int` by casting. Example: `int nValue=(int) 'a'`.

Since there is a numerical value associated to 'a' and another one associated with 'z', you could use some simple math to solve your problem.

See:

```
int aNumericalValue = (int) 'a';
int zNumericalValue = (int) 'z';
char characterToConvert = ...;
int characterToConvertAsNumericalValue = (int) characterToConvert;

int resultCharacterAsNumericalValue = zNumericalValue - (characterToConvertAsNumericalValue - aNumericalValue);
char resultCharacter = (char) resultCharacterAsNumericalValue;
```

Or, you could write all of this as a single line of code:

```
char resultCharacter = (char) ((int) 'z' - ((int) characterToConvert - (int) 'a'));
```

And finally, if you are willing to hardcode some ASCII values:

```
char resultCharacter = (char) (122 - ((int) characterToConvert - 97));
```

Note that this is for lowercase letters. For caps, use 'A' (ascii 65), 'Z' (ascii 90).